# Should I use REST style URLs with PUT and DELETE in my web app?

Tags: ajax, http, rest, url

I have a SPA (single page application) so it uses AJAX extensively for getting and saving data to and from the server.  In one case I allow the admin to view/add/edit/delete users.  Some current urls for this area looked something like:

```
(GET) /users?userId=1   // get user with id of 1
(POST) /users?userId=1&firstName=Jim    // update the first name of the user with id 1
(POST) /users?firstName=Bob    // create a new use with the first name Bob
(POST) /users?userId=1&delete=true    // delete user with id of 1
```

Having spent some time working on a RESTful API in a related project, I'm wondering if it's preferred to use HTTP types (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) in a web app as well.  Also, is it better to use a path parameter for user id instead of a query parameter?  So are these urls (rewrite of the ones above) a better option in the long run:

```
(GET) /users/1   // get user with id of 1
(PUT) /users/1?firstName=Jim    // update the first name of the user with id 1
(POST) /users?firstName=Bob    // create a new use with the first name Bob
(DELETE) /users/1    // delete user with id of 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes you should. You should be as RESTful as possible which means using HTTP semantics to their fullest. However the reality is a bit more murky, several older browsers, I don't need to name names, don't support anything but `GET` and `POST`. So the current recommendation until those browsers go out of support, or until you drop support for those browsers, is to have backup methods that do the same thing but on `POST`, usually with an extra parameter or segment in the url.

Comment: I should be clear that I'm not designing a RESTful API in this case, but just a typical SPA web app with lots of AJAX.  I need to support IE 8 and higher along with modern versions of Firefox and Chrome.  Will those browsers support PUT and DELETE through AJAX?  I know html forms are a different story.

Comment: It appears that insofar as the browser supports native `XMLHTTPRequest` it should work fine in AJAX. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers